# Query statement works in SQL Server but it's not working in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    nome as Nome, Cognome As Cognome, DataConsegna as Data, 
    'RichiesteAttrezzatura' [Tipo Richiesta] 
FROM 
    RichiesteAttrezzatura 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    nome AS Nome, Cognome as Cognome, DataConsegna as Data, 
    'RichiesteMateriali' [Tipo Richiesta] 
FROM 
    RichiesteMateriali 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    nome AS Nome, Cognome as Cognome, giorno AS Data, 
    'RichiesteVestiario' [Tipo Richiesta] 
FROM 
    RichiesteVestiario
```

As in the title the problem is that it works in SQL Server when I execute it, but when I try in C# it just returns an empty table.

From what I understood looking on the net and in this forum the problem comes with the single quotes.

This is my function

```
adonet db;

DataProvider()
{ 
    db = new adonet();
    db.CreaConnessione();
}

public DataTable getRichiesteForDGV(int id)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string richiesteVestiario = "RichiesteVestiario";
    string richiesteMateriali = "RichiesteMateriali";
    string richiesteAttrezzatura = "RichiesteAttrezzatura";

    string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT nome as Nome, Cognome As Cognome, DataConsegna as Data, '" + richiesteAttrezzatura + "' [Tipo Richiesta] FROM RichiesteAttrezzatura " +
                "UNION SELECT DISTINCT nome AS Nome, Cognome as Cognome, DataConsegna as Data, '" + richiesteMateriali + "' [Tipo Richiesta] FROM RichiesteMateriali " +
                "UNION SELECT DISTINCT nome AS Nome, Cognome as Cognome, giorno AS Data, '" + richiesteVestiario + "' [Tipo Richiesta] FROM RichiesteVestiario";

    db.EseguiQueryWithParams(sql, new SqlParameter("@id", id));

    return dt;
}

public DataTable EseguiQueryWithParams(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        ApriConnessione();
        string nometab = "dump";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        try
        {
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            if (dset.Tables[nometab] != null)
                dset.Tables[nometab].Clear();

            adp.Fill(dset, nometab);
            DataTable d = dset.Tables[nometab];
            //d.Columns;
            return d;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
            //throw new System.Exception("Errore nella lettura della tabella");

        }
        finally
        {
            adp.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            ChiudiConnessione();
        }

    }
```

Any help is appreciated. I've updated the post, since I understood that the problem comes with my C#

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: SQL Server wouldn't care if the query is executed in C# or in SQL Server Management Studio. The first query should work anywhere, if it doesn't then the problem is not in the SQL Server part but on the C# part. Show us the C# code that you use to execute it. The second query OTOH is not valid SQL. PS: by the way, you can drop the DISTINCTs, because UNION always removes the duplicates, otherwise you should use UNION ALL.

Comment: I'm going to update the post. Thank you

Comment: Why are you injecting values into your SQL statement? **Parametrise**.

Comment: Why are you setting an `@id` parameter, when that parameter isn't at all used in your query??

Comment: I knew that you guys would ask that... I'm going to explain it but pls don't be so rough I'm really a beginner. So I used `@id` as parameter because If I used my function `public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string sql, CommandType type, string tableName)` I need to write the tableName, but in the above query I'm getting results from 3 tables so I don't know what table to put there, meanwhile in `EseguiNonQueryWithParams` it just doesn't require a Table Name.

Comment: @Larnu It's fine in this case, because the values are constants. But yes, if there's any thought of ever letting a user choose this, they need to be parameters.

Comment: Two things: **1)** write the value of `sql` to a log file just before running the query. Then, copy paste that string from the log file to Sql Server Management Studio. You should be able to debug it from there. **2)** The result of `adp.Fill()` should tell you the number of rows. Check that, and see how many it tells you. You're looking for a number greater than 0.

Comment: Also, your query looks at three tables, but it puts everything into one result set. You can put anything you want for that tablename.

Comment: You are ignoring the result of EseguiQueryWithParams and returning the (empty) datatable that you created at the start of getRichiesteForDGV

Comment: "Any help is appreciated. " - LEARN TO DEBUG. Get tehe SQL string that is actually SENT. See whether this workd in SSMS. Oh, and maybe - just maybe - tell us about the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, I'm gonna spend a minute suggesting some changes to `EseguiQueryWithParams()` that are too large to fit as a comment.

For starters, the way it handles the connection [is not good practice.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query/398790#398790) Read the link until you understand it. Instead, you want a common method or property that tells you the **connection string**, and nothing else. The other changes to the method should all be understandable in the code:

```
private DataTable EseguiQuery(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    // The method should only supply the string. 
    // DO NOT TRY TO REUSE THE SAME CONNECTION OBJECT!
    string connectionString = Connessione();
    var dset = new DataSet(); //creating a new dataset for this query also means there's no need to check and clear it further down

    //Using blocks guarantee the items are disposed, even if an exception is thrown
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapater(cmd))
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql; //cmd.CommandType already has "Text" as the default value
        if (parameters is object && parameters.Length > 0)
        {   //conditional test lets us skip the parameters argument when calling the method
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        }
        adp.Fill(dset); // Fill() opens and closes the connection automatically
        return dset.Tables[0]; 
    }
} // No try/catch anywhere, because the old try/catch didn't do anything
```

See how much less code that it is (17 lines vs 31, after cleaning up comments), but it accomplishes all the same things. Even opening and closing the connection is covered, even it's less obvious where. Additionally, it allows you to skip passing parameters, like this:

```
var result = db.EseguiQuery(sql)
```

One other important change is making this method **private**. Do the same for other Execute/Esegui methods. The `getRichiesteForDGV()`, as well as other methods which talk to the DB, should then also be (public) members of the type represented by the `db` variable. In this way, you obtain good separation of concerns between your data access and your user interface. There's no way in your application to access the database without use a public member of the that type.

Finally, I removed the `WithParams` part of the name, because I believe it's poor practice to provide an overload that doesn't expect them. Parameters are so important, you want the message loud and clear to developers they're expected to use them. And since the table name isn't really important and you can called stored procedures with the default `Text` CommandType by prefacing them the `exec`, this can completely replace the old `ExecuteQuery()` method.

---

With all that out of the way, we can finally address the actual question. `EseguiQueryWithParams()` returns a `DataTable`, but this return value is ignored. It's never connected with the `dt` variable declared and returned in `getRichiesteForDGV()`. Fix it, along with my suggested changes, like this:

```
public DataTable getRichiesteForDGV(int id)
{
    string richiesteVestiario = "RichiesteVestiario";
    string richiesteMateriali = "RichiesteMateriali";
    string richiesteAttrezzatura = "RichiesteAttrezzatura";

    string sql = $"SELECT DISTINCT nome as Nome, Cognome As Cognome, DataConsegna as Data, '{richiesteAttrezzatura}' [Tipo Richiesta] FROM RichiesteAttrezzatura " +
                "UNION SELECT DISTINCT nome AS Nome, Cognome as Cognome, DataConsegna as Data, '{richiesteMateriali}' [Tipo Richiesta] FROM RichiesteMateriali " +
                "UNION SELECT DISTINCT nome AS Nome, Cognome as Cognome, giorno AS Data, '{richiesteVestiario}' [Tipo Richiesta] FROM RichiesteVestiario";

    // this should be a member of the `db` class now, so "db." is implied
    return EseguiQuery(sql);
}
```

Comment: Wow what a nice answer I've received in this question! Usually people answer but do not explain where I'm doing it wrong or other stuff. There is surely a lot to learn but this explanation is so clean. Thank you Sir.